# How to add some images in a list

Tags: flutter, dart

I am just a beginner in flutter, i want to read some images from a folder and put them in a list but i can't read them whatever i do,in console i get a type of error called _Namespace in my terminal, my folder names doesn't contain special characters or anything else, i just want to create a basic app (web app, not android/ios) , where when the program starts shows some images in a ListView.builder.

```
Future<List<File>> getImagesFromFolder(String folderPath) async {
  Directory directory = Directory(folderPath);
  List<File> imageFiles = [];
  int i = 0;
  if (await directory.exists()) {
    List<FileSystemEntity> entities = directory.listSync();
    for (var entity in entities) {
      if (entity is File) {
        imageFiles.add(entity);  
      }
    }
  }
  return imageFiles;
}

class ImageListFromFolder extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageListFromFolderState createState() => _ImageListFromFolderState();
}

class _ImageListFromFolderState extends State<ImageListFromFolder> {
  List<File> _imageFiles = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadImages();
  }

  Future<void> _loadImages() async {
    String folderPath = '(here i insert the path using '/' but is still not reading )';
    List<File> images = await getImagesFromFolder(folderPath);
    setState(() {
      _imageFiles = images;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the code encountered an issue due to the failure to recognize the / character as a valid directory separator where the image files are located. Also, I've refined the code to enhance efficiency and readability for future use.

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class FolderFileList {
  final String folderPath;

  // Constructor that takes the folder path as an argument
  FolderFileList(this.folderPath);

  /// Returns a list of file directories for supported image files in the specified folder.
  /// If the folder does not exist or any error occurs, it will return an empty list.
  Future<List<String>> getFilesInFolder() async {
    // List of supported file extensions
    final List<String> supportedExtensions = ['png', 'jpg', 'tiff'];
    final List<String> fileDirectories = [];

    try {
      // Get the directory object for the specified folder path
      final Directory folderDirectory = Directory(folderPath);

      if (await folderDirectory.exists()) {
        // List all files in the folder
        final List<FileSystemEntity> files = folderDirectory.listSync();

        for (final file in files) {
          if (file is File) {
            // Get the file extension and convert it to lowercase
            final String extension = file.path.split('.').last.toLowerCase();

            // Check if the file extension is supported
            if (supportedExtensions.contains(extension)) {
              // Add the file directory to the list
              fileDirectories.add(file.path);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle any errors that occur during file retrieval
      print('Error: An error occurred while retrieving files. $error');
    }

    // Returns the list of file directories for supported image files
    return fileDirectories;
  }

class ImageReader {
  final String imagePath;

  // Constructor that takes the file path as an argument
  ImageReader(this.imagePath);

  /// Reads the image from the specified file path and returns it as an [Image] object.
  /// Returns null if any error occurs during image reading.
  Future<Image?> readImage() async {
    try {
      final File imageFile = File(imagePath);

      if (await imageFile.exists()) {
        final List<int> imageBytes = await imageFile.readAsBytes();
        final Image? decodedImage = decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(imageBytes));

        return decodedImage;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle any errors that occur during image reading
      print('Error: An error occurred while reading the image. $error');
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sadly , i don't know how to implement your code ,i tried something but i get the same error _Namespace, when i call the constuctor this is how i do it: final reader = ImageReader('D:/images/');/

Comment: @GigeaNicusor given other answers from this user, it's not unlikely that if was generated by ChatGPT. Please be extra careful and don't trust it blindly. If in serious doubt, flag it.